# WooCommerce Paypal - Disallow Payment based on PayPal Billing Address (Country Restriction)

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-sandbox

A client of mine has some legal provisions that only allow him to offer PayPal as a payment method if the buyer's billing address is located in a specific country.

Naturally you can disable payment methods based on the billing address the buyer provides via WooCommerce. However, that is quite easy to manipulate.

PayPal asked them to implement a query, AFTER the buyer chose PayPal, signed into his account and accepted the payment method, to check if the billing address the buyer provided in his actual PayPal account is also located in that specific country. If so, the buyer proceeds to the 3rd checkout step and can finish his order. IF NOT, the buyer will be redirected to the 2nd checkout step, sees a note "This payment method is not available for your country" or whatever and can choose another payment method. So basically, the query has to check if the billing address is in a specific country and then decline the "payment execute" command.

I'm using the standard PayPal gateway that comes with WooCommerce. Does anyone have any idea how to make this work?

PS: Yes, retrieving the billing address from PayPal is usually not possible. However, my client got a special permit from PayPal to do so. So that's not an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Using the [PayPal Checkout](https://woocommerce.com/products/woocommerce-gateway-paypal-checkout/) plugin for WooCommerce, validate whether the response of the `METHOD=GetExpressCheckoutDetails` API call to PayPal contains the country you want, and use this to decide whether to let the customer proceed or not.